# Laravel Controller not working when getting specific data

Tags: php, oop, laravel, web, edit

please help I'm stuck in this code for about an Hour

```
                        @foreach ($myemployee as $mytask) 
                        <tr>
                            <td >
                                {{$mytask->firstname}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{$mytask->lastname}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{$mytask->position}}
                            </td>

                             <td>
                                <a href="{{action('EmployeesController@empedit', $mytask->id) }}">Delete</a>
                            </td>
```

I just keep getting Error Code: 500, I figured out that the problem is in this line of code

```
       <a href="{{action('EmployeesController@empedit', $mytask->id) }}">Delete</a>
```

Just want to know what is the correct syntax for sending data to controller with ID, Thanks

this is my code for controller

```
        class EmployeesController extends BaseController
        {

                public function home()
                {
                    return View::make('Home');
                }

                public function register()
                {
                    $myemployee=Employee::all();
                    return View::make('registration',compact('myemployee'));
                }

                public function registerEmp()
                {
                    $input = Input::all();

                    $command = new Employee;
                    $command->firstname=$input['firstname'];
                    $command->lastname=$input['lastname'];
                    $command->position=$input['position'];
                    $command->save();

                    return Redirect::action('EmployeesController@register');


                }

                public function edit()
                {
                    return View::make('edit',compact('employee'));
                }


        }

        ?>
```

and this one is for the route

```
            Route::get('/', 'EmployeesController@Home');
            Route::get('register', 'EmployeesController@register');
            Route::post('register', 'EmployeesController@registerEmp');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('EmployeesController@empedit', $mytask->id) }}">Delete</a>
```

`action()` is a method in the URL class, so that should work.

**Update**: No need to use `URL::` as there is a helper method, my bad. The problem seems to be that you need to pass the second argument as an array. Try this:

```
<a href="{{ action('EmployeesController@empedit', array($mytask->id)) }}">Delete</a>
```

**Update 2:** If the posted code is complete, then you are missing the `@endforeach` and a `</tr>`.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: As I said, you need to be more specific. Post a more detailed error report, otherwise it is way to unclear. Also post the full code, the current one is uncomplete and therfore not very helpful.

Comment: I updated my question sir, maybe you can help me out now. thanks

Comment: No. I have @endforeach and /tr

Comment: Sorry, but it is getting too annoying. I asked you to post the code, but you did not even manage to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created proper route for your action. You may need to to create it for proper working. Add this to your app/route.php

```
Route::get('empedit', 'EmployeesController@edit');
```